# al pasar pasarámetros deseo enviar mas de uno, de echo son 5 y una lista finformación net core MVC

Tags: mvc, netcore

estoy trabajando en net core y mi script queda así:

```
    function impresion() {


        var combo = document.getElementById("cboCliente");
        var cliente = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;


        location.href = '@Url.Action("Remision", "Home")' + '?cliente=' + cliente;
    }
```

el código funciona para enviar un solo parámetro pero ya cuando pongo 2 me marca error, la manera para poner 2 yo lo estoy colocando así:

```
    function impresion() {

        var consecutivo = document.getElementById('txtConsecutivo').value;
        //var cliente = document.getElementById('cboCliente').seleted;

        var combo = document.getElementById("cboCliente");
        var cliente = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;



        console.log(consecutivo,cliente)
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Remision", "Home")' + '?cliente=' + cliente + '?consecut=' + consecut;
    }
```

podrían orientarme cual es la forma correcta de poner más de un parámetro?

Comment: Los `Query String` inician con `?` (solo debes tener uno) y se concatenan con `&`, tu has puesto dos `?`. Es decir, el formato es el sigte: `www.url.com/param1/pag?variable1=valor1&variable2=valor2&variable3=valor3`. Esto del lado del cliente, ahora en el servidor debes tener correctamente ingresado los argumentos en el `Action` correspondiente

Comment: excelente gracias ha sido de gran ayuda